# How to read .grd file as raster in R?

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to read and stack several .grd files and export it as .nc file in R. I am using the following commands

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(RNetCDF)
library(rgdal)

files <-list.files(path="G:/Gridded data/", 
           pattern="GRD", all.files=FALSE, full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
s <- stack(files)
rstack <- raster(files[1])
```

But it is giving the following error

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
> Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  :
> Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
> Can anyone help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would try `pattern="\\.grd$"` (this means, the file ends on ".grd"). Or at least `pattern="grd"` instead of `pattern="GRD"`. (or use `ignore.case = TRUE`)

```
files <- list.files(path="G:/Gridded data/",  pattern="\\.grd$", full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
```

Comment: It is not working. I am sharing two data file if you can do it and share the code with me then it will be of great help to me (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MIbvdyrZGzbvQZKUUVKS_Xu2swxRbDIN)